# An upper bound for graph chromatic number related with $ω^2$

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

In graph coloring I have heared the inequality 
$\chi(G) \le \omega(G) ^2$ where $\chi$ is [graph chromatic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring) and $\omega$ is [graph clique number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_(graph_theory)) in an arbitary graph G but actually I'm not sure whether it's true as far as I wasn't succesful proving it.
I would appreciate if you could clarify.

Comment: What do you mean by the symbol $\omega^2$?

Comment: @LaarsHelenius In graph theory $\omega$ is the maximal sub graph which is a clique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's false: the Mycielski graph construction ([Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mycielskian)) shows that there exist graphs $G$ with $\chi(G)$ arbitrarily large but $\omega(G)=2$.

We do have $\chi(G) = \omega(G)$ when $G$ is a [perfect graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_graph). (This is sort of a by-definition claim, but perfect graphs are now known to be characterized by the [strong perfect graph theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_perfect_graph_theorem), giving my statement some content.)

And, of course, we always have $\chi(G) \ge \omega(G)$.